# Make button with function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a button with click function to run my jquery:

```
Function tester(){alert("test")}
```

My raw html button code is:

```
<button class="t1" id="52" onClick="tester()">sometext</button>
```

But i want to make the button using just jquery code...

How can I make this button with jquery?

Comment: by make you're asking about how can create the button in runtime? or how can you handle the event in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use append() function

have a div

```
<div id="buttonholder"> </div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('#buttonholder').append('<button class="t1" id="52" onClick="tester()">sometext</button>');
```

or

```
$('<button class="t1" id="52" onClick="tester()">sometext</button>').appendTo('#buttonholder');
```

Btw

**Function** .. **f** should be small